# Azure Wordpress MySQL performance

Tags: wordpress, azure, galera, azure-mysql-database, mariadb-10.6

I have 3 mariadb galera db's, 2 nginx/php machines at these sizes
DBs - E8ds_v5, nginx/php-fpm - D4ds_V5
I am getting really bad performance from mariadb.  These machines are in the same vnet, but different subnets for db and web.  The two nginx/php-fpm servers share web files through and azure files premium nfs share which seems to be working OK.

I have tried upgrading the storage of the DBs to P40 with no change in performance.  Currently testing with an upgraded instance size(only one server to test) to E20ds_v5, Storage at Premium SSDv2 (30,000 IOPS, 500 MB/s)

I am running wordpress benchmarks and timing db queries to a barebones wordpress install with absolutely no change in score no matter what is done.  The barebones wordpress install is pointed directly to the upgraded machine at the moment.  My next step is to try and use MySQL Flex, but it would be great if I could get this self hosted mariadb working.. no matter what amount of tuning is done, things seem to remain the same, slow.

I think the biggest problem is that I get terrible performance if MySQL is not running locally to where PHP is being processed.

[Galera DB INFO requested](https://justpaste.it/c90w6)

Here are the benchmark scores from [Wordpress Hosting Benchmark tool](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpbenchmark/) with different setups.

[Benchmark of nginx/php-fpm/mariadb on the same VM (Standard_D1_v2) - NODATA](https://imgur.com/KlShP7M)

[Benchmark of nginx/php-fpm/mariadb on the same VM (Standard_D1_v2) - WITH DATA](https://imgur.com/U5o0hUI)

[When using 2 NGINX/PHP-FPM servers with 1 separate MySQL 8 FLEX DB (different subnet) Business Critical, E16ds_v5, 16 vCores, 128 GiB RAM, 256 GiB storage NO DATA](https://imgur.com/M3PZ6Rt)

[When using 2 NGINX/PHP-FPM servers with 1 separate MySQL 8 FLEX DB (different subnet) Business Critical, E16ds_v5, 16 vCores, 128 GiB RAM, 256 GiB storage DATA](https://imgur.com/tSEiM6a)

[When using 2 NGINX/PHP-FPM servers with 3 dbs(galera, different subnet from web) mentioned above DATA](https://imgur.com/O2dHzNS)

[When using 2 NGINX/PHP-FPM servers with 1 maria db (same subnet) mentioned above NO DATA](https://imgur.com/UdsJIkS)

Comment: See if this plugin helps:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores on Azure MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions. Welcome to SO.

Comment: thanks, added dbinfo and benchmark info/images

Comment: Where are the 3 Galera nodes physically located?

Comment: Those imgurs may be useful for comparing different configurations for _the given benchmark_, but are they representative of _your_ application?

Comment: All things Azure, East US.  The 5 problem VMs are in 2 AV-Sets, one for DB one for WEB.  The purpose of the images was to display better scores for DB while using a small vm with mysql running on it vs bad scores if mysql runs outside of localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the DB info posted. Additional DB information request, please. OS, Version? RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME for data storage on Azure MySQL Host server? Workload Analysis in process.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04
MariaDB 10.6
8 cpus, 64G RAM (Azure E8ds_v5)
Premium SSD, rated at a maximum of 2300 IOPS

Comment: @naw_  Since you know the Premium SSD is rated at max of 2300 IOPS, consider changing your innodb_io_capacity to 2300  from the 7500 you have in your config at this time.

Comment: Workload Analysis has been completed, please see Answer dated 2024 03 25 about 11:19 for Suggestions to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the slow Azure Files NFS system.  Even though it was a Premium(Hot) NFS 4.1 fileshare, it was too slow.

We built our own HA NFS server and haven't had problems with the DB anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your Azure Server portal, settings, parameters

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=24G  # from 48G until more than 10G is used
thread_pool_size=6  # from 16 you only have 8 cpu's 
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384  # from 4M to reduce innodb_data_read RPS of 114,229 
read_buffer_size=524288  # from 3M to reduce innodb_data_read RPS of 114,229 
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to reduce 90% CPU cycles used for function.
```

There are many more opportunities to improve performance. Please view my profile.

Observation,
innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads had 1,878,540 reported in 16 hours.  This is usually caused by table(s) with NO Primary Key.  For a query to find the tables of this nature, please provide an email address.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, this did lead me to the answer.  It's actually the fact that Azure Files premium NFS is really slow in general.  Maybe due to the many small files in wordpress.  However, this did show me that there is tuning to be done within the DB.  A good amount of the misconfigurations were due to the alternative speeds in disk and VM sizes we were trying.

Comment: We are here to assist.  When you are ready.

Comment: What is your perception of performance after applying the Suggestions of 2024-03-25 about 11:19 ?  Better/worse?

Comment: roughly the same, I think once we deal with the storage issue, we can hone in on the DB problems